# Easy recursive factorial function

Tags: java, recursion

I'm testing many options in java so I want to do an easy recursive function in java.

I use console to execute the program, it receives a parameter but always when I try the recursion with any parameter that should be more than 1, it shows 0.

```
public class rec{
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        int h = 0;
        int numero = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int factor = 0;

        if ( numero == 0 || numero == 1){
            System.out.println(1);
        } else {
            int xpi = factorial(numero-1);
            System.out.println(factor);
        }
    }

    public static int factorial (int n){
        System.out.println("lol");
        if(n==0) {
            return 0;
        } else{ 
            return n* (n-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would have been easier to paste the code into your question, so that you would have an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @rgettman im unable to do because stackoverflow says that the code is weird or something like that, I will try again.

Comment: If you expect help, paste ([edit]) the relevant part(s) of your code inside your question.

Comment: Do not try to create a *snippet*, use **{}** for code formatting

Comment: There's no recursion in the above code.

Comment: @JamesKPolk tell me why please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is not recursive as it doesn't invoke itself. This would be an example of recursion:

```
public static int factorial(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 1 : n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

Comment: So recursive means that has to invoke itself! ok, my thanks, so useful for me and maybe other ppl

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at these lines of your code:

```
int xpi = factorial(numero-1);
System.out.println(factor);
```

You put the result of function to `xpi` variable, but then you print `factor` variable. Printing `xpi` should work.

```
System.out.println(xpi);
```